# Node.js node-postgres get JSON objects from API call

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have followed the node-postgres.org instruction at https://node-postgres.com/guides/async-express to connect via `async`/`await` to my postgres table `users`.

Navigating to `localhost:3000/users/1` will return the JSON string for user 1 in the browser. I have extended this a bit to return all users at `localhost:3000/users`. My `routes/user.js` script is:

```js
const Router = require('express-promise-router')

const db = require('../db')

// create a new express-promise-router
// this has the same API as the normal express router except
// it allows you to use async functions as route handlers
const router = new Router()

// export our router to be mounted by the parent application
module.exports = router

router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Where id = ');
  const { id } = req.params
  const { rows } = await db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [id])
  res.send(rows[0])
})

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('*');
  const { rows } = await db.all('SELECT * FROM users')
  res.send(rows)
})
```

the index for this route at `routes/index.js` is simply:

```js
const users = require('./user')

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use('/users', users)
}
```

and the `db.query()` and `db.all()` functions that I am awaiting are in `db/index.js`:

```js
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool()
module.exports = {
    query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
    all: (text) => pool.query(text)
}
```

The routes are required in my main `app.js` file:

```js
// ./app.js
const express = require('express')
const mountRoutes = require('./routes')
const cons = require('consolidate')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
mountRoutes(app)

// Assign Dust Engine to .dust files
app.engine('dust', cons.dust);

// Set .dust as the default extension
app.set('view engine', 'dust');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// Set Public Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Body parser and Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

app.get('/', function(reg, res) {
  console.log('Root');
  res.render('index', {hallo:'test'})
});

//Server 
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server Started on Port 3000');
});
```

So far this works beautifully! I get the JSON strings that I want and I can build upon this sort of API by extending my routes and queries.

**Question:**
How can I return my JSON object `rows` back to `app.js` to `res.render()` it there?

*or*

Can I do something like this anywhere in my app:

```
jsonVar = GetMyJson('/users/1');
console.log(jsonVar);
```

returns:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "usr_name": "Michael"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "usr_name": "Thomas"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "usr_name": "Paul"
  }
]
```

I could then pass whatever route and parameters I want into `GetMyJson()` and deal with the resulting JSON.

This may be a trivial question for javascript devs ...

Thanks!

**EDIT 21/12/2017**

I have created a frontend script called `graphs.js` that simply logs my result when i call the fuction `api('/user/1')`.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("clickMe");
if (el.addEventListener)
    el.addEventListener("click", api, false);
else if (el.attachEvent)
    el.attachEvent('onclick', api);

var api = function(what){
    // Action
    sendRequest(what, function(result){
        if(result){
           log(result);
         }
    })

}

var apiEndpoint = 'http://localhost:3000/'
function sendRequest(_path, cb) {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open('GET', apiEndpoint+_path);
    oReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            cb(JSON.parse(this.response));
        }
        else{
            cb(null);
        }
    }
    oReq.send();
}

function log(msg){
    console.log(msg);
}
```

**BUT**
Is that a proper way of doing it in javascript?

Comment: in your api you can do  res.json() and return the needed json

Answer (score 0):

You have to get it from `database`. Making self call will not be an ideal solution. So you can do following

```
const db = require('../db') // fix the location of db.js

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  db.all('SELECT * FROM users').then(function({ rows }) {
    res.render('index', rows)
  })
})
```

Best would be to make an `userRepository.js` and add code related to `db` over there. Then use that repository at both places.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you correctly. Isn't the `db/index.js` like a repo that manages my queries? How can I avoid to do a `res.render()` inside `db/` or `routes/`? If possible, I would like to get the JSON object back at `app.js`

Comment: I guess, you want to send `rows` object to your `template` where your are going to write some `html` to display it, right?

Comment: Yes, whatever is in `rows` will be sent to different scripts that handle the rendering. Eventually, the `rows` include statistics which will be displayed as a table, as a scatterplot, as a histogram. Making separate requests is not reasonable since the table will be rather large.

Comment: So you want get rows in frontend via ajax call and then send it back to server?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go about it would be something like this:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('*');
  const { rows } = await db.all('SELECT * FROM users')
  res.render('user', rows)
});
```

Instead of `res.send` you do `res.render`

Comment: While this works, I am looking for a way to get the JSON object to my `app.js`. Sorry, If I am lacking the proper javascript vocabulary to explain it. Is it possible to pass the JSON object `rows` back to `app.js`? Eventually, the JSON object will be a table of statistics and I want to send it to different scripts which then render scatterplots, histograms, ... 
I do not want to render in the API. Thanks

Comment: You could use `app.locals.user = rows || {}`, this will make it available to all request during the application runtime.